# Postgresql WHERE statement with JSON columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Assume the following `posts` table in a Postgresql 9.3 database

```
|id|name|properties|
--------------------
```

Where `properties` is a JSON column.

An example JSON would be:

```
{
  "comments":[
    {
      "user_id":1,
      "comment":"foo"
    },
    {
      "user_id":2,
      "comment":"bar"
    },
    {
      "oddCase":2,
      "thisShouldStillWork":true 
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I issue a SELECT statement with an "AND" or "or" WHERE?

So one would be able to:

- Select all the posts where **at least** user_id 1 OR user_id 2 OR user_id n ... has commented.
- Select all the posts where **at least** user_id 1 AND user_id 2 AND user_id n ... has commented on.

EDIT: Looks like `json_array_elements` with a dynamically generated query will work.

Comment: what postgres version? what does 'at least' mean? can at least be omitted?  it seems that some of the contain operators would work: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

Comment: This will work for the OR case? WITH tmp (posts) AS 
(SELECT json_array_elements(properties->'comments') det, id   FROM posts)
SELECT * FROM tmp JOIN posts p ON p.id=tmp.id WHERE 
    posts->>'user_id'='1' OR  posts->>'user_id'='2'

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for the second question.

```
 SELECT id,
 comment_user_id 
 FROM (
        SELECT id, 
               (json_array_elements(properties->'comments')->>'user_id')::int AS comment_user_i
          FROM post
    ) I 
 WHERE comment_user_id = any(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```